# dependency:copy-dependencies include plugin dependencies

Tags: maven

How to copy project's plugin dependencies? I run

```
mvn -DuseRepositoryLayout=true -DoutputDirectory=projectRepo dependency:copy-dependencies
```

but only project dependencies copied, so offline build fails:

```
D:\proj>mvn package -offline -Dmaven.repo.local=projectRepo 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
...
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its 
dependencies could not be resolved: Cannot access central (http://repo.maven.ap
ache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven
-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 has not been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 1]
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [dependency:go-offline](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html)

> > Goal that resolves all project dependencies, including plugins and reports and their dependencies.

Comment: I think about different ways to do what i want, go-offline wit target and copy-dependencies include plugins is one of them. I found perfect solution with go-offline. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559635/download-maven-project-dependencies-to-build-offline-later/20798638#20798638)